# How to get table id after POST operation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine, redmine-plugins

I have to get the row id after submission of a form.

My model is Boxelement.rb

```
    def create
        if @boxelement.save
                puts params[:boxelement]
        end
    end
```

Output is:

```
    {"name"=>"fwqfew", "project_id"=>"1", "author_id"=>"1", "private_flag"=>"0"}
```

But I need to know the id of the newly created row.
How can I get it?

Comment: Replace puts params[:boxelment] with puts @boxelment.id?

Comment: Can you be more precise?What is the code in your controller.Can you post it.?

Comment: Cool, I guess I'll write it up as an answer...

Comment: Sure, please write it as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

The params hash won't have the id since that's being assigned when you call save.  So even though you're accessing the params after you perform the save, Rails doesn't update the params hash.  You need to just access id directly on @boxelment:

```
def create
  @boxelment = Boxelement.new(params[:boxelement])
  if @boxelement.save
    puts @boxelement.id
  end
end
```